# Silverlight Converter to show decimals for two places

Tags: silverlight-4.0, decimal, ivalueconverter

I want to display a decimal in a textbox with two decimals. When the page loads the value in the textbox is displayed with two decimals ("0.00") . When I change the value to say 10, it is just showing as 10. How can I show it as "10.00"

Following is my Converter.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        decimal convertedBudget;
        if (value == null)
        {
            convertedBudget = 0.0M;
        }
        else
        {
            convertedBudget = (decimal)value;
        }
        return string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", Math.Round(convertedBudget, 2));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        decimal convertedBudget = 0;
        if(value!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
           convertedBudget =  System.Convert.ToDecimal(value.ToString());
        }
        return Math.Round(convertedBudget, 2);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `ValueConverter` for this, just bind `TextBox.Text` to your `decimal` and use string formatting on the `TextBox` itself. **If you want to update value after entering text then capture appropriate event and change it.**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication2">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:VM x:Name="VM"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyValue, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:0.00\}}" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus_1" />
    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,189,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="{Binding MyValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="293"/>
</Grid>
```

---

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_LostFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var v = (VM)this.DataContext;
        v.MyValue = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)sender).Text);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VM()
    {

    }

    private decimal myValue;
    public decimal MyValue
    {
        get { return myValue; }
        set { myValue = value; OnChanged("MyValue"); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnChanged(string pName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));
    }
}
```

Comment: @StawWho I tried the same using StringFormat='N2', but it just displays the decimals when the page is loaded. When I change the value to some other digit, the decimals are not shown.

Comment: @Stawwho Appreciate ur code.. But just manually enter 5 in the textbox and lose its focus.. It is still showing as 5. I want that to be displayed as "5.00".

Comment: Well, you didn't exactly ask about changing TextBox text to include two decimal places, after its text has been changed.

Comment: My bad.. i should have mentioned it. I thought may be it can be done in some other way. Accepting it as answer .. Thanks :)